# mountmanager only opens from command line not launcher

Tags: launcher, .desktop

Given:

```
3.2.0-53-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Thu ...UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can no longer open MountManager from the launcher.
MM starts from the command line and functions normally but pauses as illustrated below. Tried re-installing MountManager as suggested in another forum session but it behaves the same. Also the MountManager.log does not record anything.  This is no big deal but just curious if this may be symptomatic of a larger problem.**

```
2 records in /etc/fstab were detected.   
[G] DBus interface was created  
[G] All devices were recieved  
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sda6"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sdb6"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sr0"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sda3"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sdb3"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sdb5"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sdb2"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sdb1"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sda5"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sda2"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sda1"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sdb"   
[I] Storage device was detected: "/dev/sda"   
[G] Parsing of  "/usr/share/mountmanager/options/common.xml"  was successful   
[G] Parsing of  "/usr/share/mountmanager/options/ntfs-3g.xml"  was successful   
[W] Parsing of  "/usr/share/mountmanager/options/ext4.xml"  was unsuccsessful   
[W] Parsing of  "/usr/share/mountmanager/options/iso9660.xml"  was unsuccsessful   
[W] Parsing of  "/usr/share/mountmanager/options/udf.xml"  was unsuccsessful   
"sni-qt/4947" WARN  09:50:41.105 void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE
```

Later discovered I was able to setup mountmanager via cairo-dock so the problem may be more with launcher than mm.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the desktop file listed below after a little research.
I still wonder where the fault lies as this just became a recent problem.

/`usr/share/applications/mountmanager-gtk.desktop`

changed `Exec=mm` to

```
Exec=/usr/bin/mountmanager
```